# What is the name of the volume delimited by two parallel planes?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, terminology

How do you call the <s>volume</s> region delimited by two parallel planes?

I know the 2-dimensional analogue is called a strip.

Apologies for this sort of naive question, but I can't seem to get an answer from any popular search engine.

Comment: a parallelepiped, but you will need 2 sets of parallel planes for a volume. Then again, maybe you mean the region? A strata perhaps?

Comment: I would use the word "slab" but I could not find a generally accepted definition as well.

Comment: "Slab" is the word that popped into my head too, but I can't find any support for it.

Comment: I saw "slab" in some old 3D modeling software, but I couldn't find any other usages outside this.

Comment: @Paul I guess I meant the region, then, if volumes have to be finite.